# usb stick pretends to be empty after worm

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender

I plugged my USB stick in an infected PC(did not know that at first) and then back to my PC. When I plugged it in my PC, Windows-Defender poped up and showed a serious warning:

> Worm:Win32/Gamarue.gen!Ink
>
> Completed action: quarantine

Now when I click at the USB device it is shown empty, although if I do rightclick and options I see that it is still 150 MB occupied, so I guess there are still the files on the USB stick. I plugged the USB device back into the infected PC and there the files were visible.

I am now in the situation that I only have the USB stick left and no access anymore to the infected PC. Is there any chance that I can recover the "hidden" files on the USB stick withouth infecting my PC?

Comment: Boot to a live Linux environment access the files there

Comment: @Ramhound thanks I have a live Linux cd now. How do I proceed then to remove the worm from the files?

Comment: It might not be possible to remove the infection off the drive without formatting the drive itself.  The current infection is was identified as a generic worm infection, and when Windows Defender quarantined the drive, you might have removed the ability to retrieve your files.